# Log Fibonacci Equals to Theta

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove that $\log F_n =  Θ(n)$. Since this is Fibonacci then recursively $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, $F_1 = 1$, $F_0 = 0$. The only way I can think of to prove this is by proving that $\log F_n$ is equal to $n$ but that I can't either. No matter what Fibonacci sequence I take the $\log$ of it is simply not equal to $n$. So I can honestly say I'm so lost right now that any input would be a appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the known explicit closed formula for $F_n$ help?

Comment: $${{F}_{n}}=\frac{{{\varphi }^{n}}-{{\psi }^{n}}}{\varphi -\psi }=\frac{{{\varphi }^{n}}-{{\psi }^{n}}}{\sqrt{5}}
\begin{align}
  & \varphi =\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 1.6180339887\cdots  \\ 
 & \psi =\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-\varphi =-\frac{1}{\varphi }\approx -0.6180339887\cdots  \\ 
\end{align}
$$
$$ \to {{F}_{n}}=\frac{{{\varphi }^{n}}-{{(-\varphi )}^{-n}}}{\sqrt{5}}=\frac{{{\varphi }^{n}}-{{(-\varphi )}^{-n}}}{2\varphi -1}\\ \to {{F}_{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot {{\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)}^{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot {{\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)}^{n}}~.$$

Comment: Theoniix. Maybe? Perhaps you see something i don't. Please elaborate.

Comment: Plz explain this example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to (and can't anyway) prove that $\log F_n$ is equal to $n$.  All you need to show is that for some constants $A$ and $B$,

$$An\le\log F_n\le Bn\quad\text{for all large }n$$

To get started, note that

$$\log F_{n+1}=\log(F_n+F_{n-1})=\log F_n+\log\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over F_n}\right)$$

and the increasing nature of the Fibonacci sequnce, $F_1\le F_2\le F_3\le\cdots$, implies

$${1\over2}={F_{n-1}\over2F_{n-1}}\le{F_{n-1}\over F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}}={F_{n-1}\over F_n}\le1$$

from which it follows that

$$\log(3/2)\le\log\left(1+{F_{n-1}\over F_n}\right)\le\log2$$

So let's let $A=\log(3/2)$ and $B=\log2$.  What we've shown is that

$$An\le\log F_n\le Bn\implies A(n+1)\le\log F_{n+1}\le B(n+1)$$

Thus, *provided we can establish a base case*, induction tells us that $\log F_n=\Theta(n)$.  The first value for which $n\log(3/2)\le\log F_n\le n\log2$ (with the OP's convention $F_1=F_2=1$) turns out to be $n=11$; however, it's easier to take $n=12$ as the base case, since $F_{12}=144=12^2$, and we have

$$6\log(3/2)=\log(729/64)\le\log(768/64)=\log12\le\log64=6\log2$$

Remark:  In point of fact, $\log F_n\approx n\log\phi$, where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2\approx1.618$, which of course lies between $3/2$ and $2$.  The approach I've given here generalizes to settings where the exact asymptotic behavior of the sequence is not so easy to pinpoint.

Comment: how do you determine that log(1+Fn−1Fn) is equal to Fn-1 ?

Comment: and how do you determine that A should be log(3/2) and B should be 2 ?

Comment: and i dont get either that you from that can just assume that that is equal to theta n. The way i have understood it then the only way to calculate that Theta n is to reach the  point where you can safely conclude that c1*g(x)=n <= f(x) <= c2*g(x) = n

Comment: to me it looks like you have proven that c1*g(x)=5*log(3/2) <= f(x) <= c2*g(x)=5*log2 so havent you just that this is Theta log k ?

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543481/need-explanation-about-https-math-stackexchange-com-questions-1972748-log-fibo) asks:  shouldn't $F_5=5, $ not $8$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thank you for pointing that out. I've fixed my answer to use the OP's numbering convention for the Fibonacci numbers. I had assumed the convention $F_0=F_1=1$, and I'm not sure why I didn't notice the OP had specified otherwise.