# Need an explanation of an answer regarding $\log F_n = \Theta(n)$, where $n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972825/409) to the question ["Log Fibonacci equals Theta"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972748/log-fibonacci-equals-to-theta/3543474#3543474), I don't understand why the solution says that the base case for $n=5$, $F_5=8$. Isn't $F_5=5$, instead?

Regards

Comment: that answer has now been updated to comply with your numbering convention for Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $F_5=5$.  The fact that it is $F_6=8$ does not change the argument there.  You can either decrease $A$ a bit or demand a higher starting point for the bounds.  With the given $A,B$, the base case becomes $F_{11}=89$, with $11 \log (3/2)\approx 4.46, \log(89) \approx 4.49, 11\log(2) \approx 4.80$ and everything goes through.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972748/log-fibonacci-equals-to-theta/3543474#3543474 Cain said that $F_n \geq  (\sqrt{2})^n$ ... so I'm confused there too. Can someone explain that too? Thanks

Comment: I can't find the statement, but it is true for $n \ge 6$  When talking about this subject, we ignore failures for small $n$.  You should read statements like that as For large enough $n, F_n \ge (\sqrt 2)^n$

Comment: OK now which value of A can we use if we want to prove An <= log F(n) <= n Log(2) for all n > 0?

Comment: You can't for all $n \gt 0$ because $\log F(1)=\log 1 =0$ and we demand that $A$ be positive here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the linked-to answer, so I can confirm that it was a failure on my part to doublecheck the convention I had assumed, that $F_0=F_1=1$, with what the OP there specified, namely $F_1=F_2=1$.  I've fixed my answer there so that it now uses $n=12$, with $F_{12}=144$ as the base case. As Ross Millikan's answer here shows, $n=11$ can also be used as a base case, but verifying the inequalities is a bit easier for $n=12$.